# Error processing while Spring Security Configuration with Keycloak . Server And Apigateway is running but services not running. (Ver: 3.2.1)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, spring-security-config

Error processing while Spring  Security Configuration with Keycloak . Server And Apigateway is running but services not running.

I'm encountering an issue with my Spring Boot 3.2.1 application, specifically related to the SecurityAutoConfiguration.authenticationEventPublisher. When attempting to run the application, I'm facing the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.authenticationEventPublisher // ... (stack trace continues) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/SecurityFilterChain // ... (stack trace continues)`

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-04T17:50:35.914+05:30 ERROR 1716 --- [product-service] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.authenticationEventPublisher
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:789) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.devor.dev.Productservice.ProductServiceApplication.main(ProductServiceApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/SecurityFilterChain
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

I have a custom SecurityConfig class where I configure security settings for my application. I suspect there might be compatibility issues or misconfigurations. Below is the relevant part of my SecurityConfig class:

```
package com.devor.dev.discoveryserver.config;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecuriyConfig extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {
    @Value("${eureka.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${eureka.password}")
    private String password;



    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {

        UserDetails user = User.withUsername(username)
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode(password))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Errors:

1. Error processing condition on SecurityAutoConfiguration.authenticationEventPublisher:
   Description: This error indicates an issue with the auto-configuration of Spring Security's authenticationEventPublisher.

2.Failed to introspect Class [WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader:
Description: There is a problem while introspecting the WebSecurityConfiguration class during the application startup.

3.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/SecurityFilterChain:
Description: This error indicates that the class SecurityFilterChain cannot be found during runtime.

SpringBoot Version : 3.2.1

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.devor.dev</groupId>
        <artifactId>Inventory-Management</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>discovery-server</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here are the steps I've taken and my expectations:

Checked Dependencies:
I've reviewed my project's dependencies to ensure that I have the correct version of Spring Security.

Build File:
I've checked my build file (e.g., build.gradle or pom.xml) to ensure that there are no conflicting dependencies or versions.

If anyone has insights or suggestions on resolving this issue or has encountered similar problems with Spring Boot 3.2.1 and Spring Security, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you!

Comment: BTW: It looks like you should use version 4.1.0, see https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: @dur
I access only eureka through spring cloud and its works perfectly.
is it the issue because i install keycloak through docker

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` means exactly what dur has written. Your code wants to call/use a class which it did find it definition for, exactly what the error says.... _No Class Definition Found_. Means it doesnt exist. Means that you have a discrepancy in your libraries. One lib is calling another lib for a specific class and that lib doesnt have it because you have defined your library versions without checking which libraries work with other libraries. YOu have not posted a full rundown of all your libraries nor the entire stacktrace so we cant see what is calling what.

Comment: this is why stack traces, full error messages, and understanding of what is running and what libraries are in use is very important when solving these types of questions, and we cant help you as long as you are not posting a lot more information. Not single log lines.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have provide error stack which you requested.

I have 3 services Product , Order and Inventory.
1 discovery server which used eureka server and 1 api gateway which uses api-gateway.
Let me know if anything needed.

Comment: @ShubhamPatil Did you try version 4.1.0 as the documentation says?