# Spring Boot 3.2.1: Error Starting Services - IllegalStateException in SecurityAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud

I have updated Java Configuration using [Java Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html) .
SpringBoot Version : 3.2.1
I'm encountering an issue with my Spring Boot 3.2.1 application, specifically  When I run services it is not starting.. When attempting to run the application, I'm facing the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.authenticationEventPublisher
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:789) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at com.shubham.dev.orderservice.OrderServiceApplication.main(OrderServiceApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.access.WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

I have a custom SecurityConfig class where I configure security settings for my application. I suspect there might be compatibility issues or misconfigurations. Below is the relevant part of my SecurityConfig class:

```
package com.shubham.dev.discoveryserver.config;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${eureka.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${eureka.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username(username)
                .password(password)
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }



    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf->csrf.disable());
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(rQ -> rQ.anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }



}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.shubham.dev</groupId>
        <artifactId>Inventory-Management</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>discovery-server</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here is my Modules:
[image: Modules]
In this  Discovery-server and Api-gateway is running but not running services(Product,order,inventory).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Security cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092068/spring-boot-security-cause-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-s)

Comment: @Jens I tried this but getting same error

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.access.WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator`

Comment: this is basically the same question and same maven parent pom https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77935380/error-processing-while-spring-security-configuration-with-keycloak-server-and?noredirect=1#comment137398449_77935380

Comment: @Toerktumlare yes it maybe same because I'm following youtube tutorial for learning

Comment: then post the tutorial and you should explain that in the question so that we know and can tell if it is bad and outdated which it most likely is. I recommend if you want to larn to read the official doccs

Comment: @Toerktumlare Please check this: [ https://youtu.be/rbKzR6QWKLI?feature=shared ]

Comment: Also check Github Repo : [https://github.com/SaiUpadhyayula/spring-boot-microservices/tree/part-5/discovery-server]  in Branch:Part-5

Comment: Im sorry but im not going to do your work and i wont do a code review and go through your gitrepo, thats not how stack overflow works.

Comment: your parent pom https://github.com/SaiUpadhyayula/spring-boot-microservices/blob/part-5/pom.xml contains spring version 2.6 which was released 12 july 2022 that means it is almost 1 1/2 year old, the tutorial you are following is outdated, and the person that made it has not kept it up to date, or had the decency to remove it when it broke. All we can tell you is that you have a mismatch in your dependencies. You should update your parent to latest and then fix all the broken code. good luck

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thank you for the information you have given . I just provided for your reference to figure out issue . I already updated Java Configuration using https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html .  Sure , i will check the dependencies and update the parent to latest . Thank you for your inputs

Comment: java configuration hos nothing to do with this, as mentioned before, please read up on what a ClassNotFound exception, means, a class is missing, and thats because a library is trying to cal a different library of the wrong version.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks for your help . it works . I have updated all dependencies with latest versions and also Parent . Thanks for your help